# python3 problem upgrading 20.04 -> 20.10

Tags: upgrade, xubuntu, 20.10

So I'm trying to upgrade Xubuntu from 20.04 to 20.10, but I get stopped at the beginning with:

```
Checking for a new Ubuntu releaseGet:1 Upgrade tool signature [819 B] 
Get:2 Upgrade tool [1,338 kB] 
Fetched 1,339 kB in 0s (0 B/s) 
authenticate 'groovy.tar.gz' against 'groovy.tar.gz.gpg' 
extracting 'groovy.tar.gz'
Reading cache
Checking package manager
Can not upgrade 
Your python3 install is corrupted. Please fix the '/usr/bin/python3' 
symlink.
```

I did some searching and saw that this can be caused by not having python3 point to the version of python your release originally came from. But mine does (just about).

```
$ /usr/bin/python3 --version
Python 3.8.5
```

Granted it's 3.8.5 and not 3.8.2, but does that little difference matter? Do I actually have to downgrade?

I am using update-alternatives, but 3.8.5 is the only 3.8 installed.

```
$ ls -l /usr/bin/python3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 25 Jun 3 21:21 /usr/bin/python3 -> /etc/alternatives/python3
$ sudo update-alternatives --config python3
There is only one alternative in link group python3 (providing /usr/bin/python3): /usr/bin/python3.8
Nothing to configure.
```

Please advise... thanks!

Comment: Yes the difference (3.8.5 vs 3.8.2) matters.  The upgrade tool is written & tested for the `python3` version installed with the release, if it's changed the results may not be trustworthy or fail  (all *testing* if `python3` is changed fall on you to perform with the version you have installed; the tool is *tested* only with the version provided).

Comment: @guiverc that sounds a lot like an answer.

Comment: I have the same problem. Any ideas how to solve it?

Comment: @guiverc ok so I need to revert to 3.8.2, at least temporarily. There appears to be no trace of 3.8.2 still on my system, at least as far as I can tell. Uninstalling python3 threatens to uninstall 227 other things so that's not a good idea. Would `sudo apt-get install --reinstall python` be the correct options?

Comment: I would reverse whatever you did that changed the `python3` from the default. You don't specify that though you do mention "*using update-alternatives*".  Personally I'd look for clues (I use commands and leave a trail so I can document what & when I did it; my command history has time & date stamps recorded, but if package tools are used apt logs can be used too). If that's difficult, I'd likely upgrade via re-install (ie. something-else, existing partitions & no-format.. that procedure changed recently but I forget specifics as to when sorry, so can't recall if *groovy* restores all packages

Comment: @guiverc unfortunately the python change was a while back in order to fix something else that needed a newer version. My Linux skills aren't strong enough so I don't intrinsically understand everything that was going on and was using online answers to get things working. I'm hesitant to do an in-place reinstall since I'm using full-disk encryption and there are enough landmines that, just my luck, it'd fully bork my install and render it unusable. I guess I'll have to look further to see if there's a way to revert python 3.8.5 -> 3.8.2

Comment: also asked at https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2452884

Answer (score 2):

Yes the difference (3.8.5 vs 3.8.2) matters.

The upgrade tool is written & tested for the `python3` version installed with the release.

If the `python3` version is changed, the results may not be trustworthy or fail  (all *testing* if `python3` is changed fall on you to perform with the version you have installed; the tool is *tested* only with the version provided).

```
guiverc@d960-ubu2:~$  rmadison python3
 python3 | 3.2.3-0ubuntu1   | precise          | all
 python3 | 3.2.3-0ubuntu1.2 | precise-updates  | amd64, armel, armhf, i386, powerpc
 python3 | 3.4.0-0ubuntu2   | trusty           | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, powerpc, ppc64el
 python3 | 3.5.1-3          | xenial           | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, powerpc, ppc64el, s390x
 python3 | 3.6.5-3          | bionic           | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, s390x
 python3 | 3.6.7-1~18.04    | bionic-updates   | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, s390x
 python3 | 3.8.2-0ubuntu2   | focal            | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x
 python3 | 3.8.6-0ubuntu1   | groovy           | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x
 python3 | 3.8.6-0ubuntu1   | hirsute          | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x
 python3 | 3.8.6-1          | hirsute-proposed | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be closed.

It turns out the problem was not that I had python 3.8.5 instead of 3.8.2. Instead, it was the symbolic linking that update-alternatives does to /usr/bin/python3. Removing the chained symbolic links and linking directly to /usr/bin/python3.8 like it would be without update-alternatives resolved the 20.10 upgrade problem, even though python was still 3.8.5 and ultimately still referring to the same binary.

I didn't have to change python versions and am now on Xubuntu 20.10.